# C++ classes and objects getting user input using set method?

Tags: c++

I've been given an assignment where I'm supposed to create a shelf that stores supermarket products. The products class should store the product ID, manufacturer and name and include a constructor ,tostring, get+set methods.

And this part I don't get it: "create a class called Shelf to store a collection of products using a Vector/ArrayList". Does this mean I have to create the array/vector inside the class or what?

The shelf class has to have a addProduct method which takes in a product object as input and adds the object into the shelf.

Then in the driver program, I need to:

1. Create a vector/array of the product objects
2. create a shelf object
3. each time a product is placed on the shelf, the program must ask for the product ID, manufacturer & name, create a new product object, then add the product onto the shelf by calling the methods.
   The question is longer than this but I'm only stuck up to this point...

Basically the only questions I have is the

1. does 'create a shelf object' mean create a shelf vector/array?
2. how do I use the set method that gets its input from the user?

Right now(part of) my set method is like this:
(in class)

```
public:

Product(int id, string manufacturer, string name)

void setID(int newid)
```

(in driver)

```
void Product::setID(int newid){ id = newid;}
```

I'm supposed to ask for 20 inputs which I'm going to do using a for loop. But how do I change my set methods to ones that ask for user input?

Sorry for the lengthy post and thank you if you made it this far. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to talk with the instructor or customer:  the person who gave you the requirements.  Always confer with the customer before embarking on the programming.

Comment: _"But how do I change my set methods to ones that ask for user input?"_ You don't Ask for user input using another variable and pass that one to your set function.

Comment: I recommend asking the Customer if there are other types of products than books that are put on the shelf.  This could change the implementation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Err I got that part wrong lol. It's meant to be product object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure

> "create a class called Shelf to store a collection of products using a
>   Vector/ArrayList"

means: create a class Shelf which contains a Vector/ArrayList. The methods of your Shelf class should call methods of Vector/ArrayList with the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the requirements.

> create a class called Shelf to store a collection of products using a Vector/ArrayList

Looks like you need at least two classes:  `Shelf` and `Product`.  You also need some kind of container.

This could be modeled as:

```
class Product
{
};

class Shelf
{
   std::vector<Product> m_products;
};
```

> how do I use the set method that gets its input from the user?

Usually getting input from the User involves the `cin`.

```
class Product
{
  unsigned int m_id;
  public:
    void setter(void)
    {
      std::cout << "Enter product ID: ";
      cin >> m_id;
    }
};
```

Comment: Cluttering setters with input statements is bad advice.

Comment: Yes, bad advice, but it satisfies the requirements of a *"set method that gets its input from the user"*.

Comment: dude thanks a lot man, I think I've got it now. I tried this before but it seems like I needed the (void).

Answer (score 0):

> does 'create a shelf object' mean create a shelf vector/array?

let the exposed API facilitate addition of a single/multiple products.hence, pass it a vector.Shelf will have it's own vector

```
class Shelf
{
   private:
   vector<product> _products;
   public:
   void addProduct(vector<product> products){//copy the vector contents}
};
```